# MySQL error during installing Prestashop module

Tags: mysql, module, prestashop

i made module for prestashop. Just basic administration form with write into DB. But when i try to install module at Prestashop, i have this error:

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'


INSERT INTO `ps_module` (`name`, `active`, `version`) VALUES ('apishippingtextsource', '1', '0.0.1')

at line 635 in file classes/db/Db.php
629.            WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
630.        }
631.        else if (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS'))
632.        {
633.            if ($sql)
634.                throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
635.            throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
636.        }
637.    }
638. 
639.    /**
```

my install.php for sql:

```
$sql = array();

$sql[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'api_shipping_text` (
        `id_text` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id_text`)
) ENGINE=' . _MYSQL_ENGINE_ . ' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;';

foreach ($sql as $query) {
    if (Db::getInstance()->execute($query) == false) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Version of Prestashop is 1.6.0.9.

Comment: Can you check the `auto_increment` value of your `ps_module` table structure? Maybe `auto_increment` is not defined or defined to `0`

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre thanks a lot, i am idiot. I don't set auto_increment for id column. And here is i a prob, how its possible, there is modules instaled. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the `auto_increment` value of your `ps_module` table structure? Maybe `auto_increment` is not defined or set to 0.

If that's the case, you probably had an error during Database migration or installed another module messing with `auto_increment`.